# Clearing the trumbowyg editor in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wysiwyg, trumbowyg

I am currently using the [trumbowyg](http://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/) editor on a project and I am having a problems clearing the contents of the editor. Every thing is fine if I want to re-populate the editor by changing the contents of the model attached to it but it will not clear the contents of the editor when I do `$scope.editorModel = '';`. I have a Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xNRoW3jUHjQ5adgFvNMB) that explains it a bit more (*click the button at the bottom of the page*).

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that newer versions of [Trumbowyg](https://github.com/Alex-D/Trumbowyg) (2.4.2) and [trumbowyg-ng](https://github.com/irongomme/trumbowyg-ng) have good two-way binding on the model.

So, now when the model is directly set to '', both the model and the trumbowyg editor blank out.

```
<pre>editorModel: {{editorModel}}</pre>
<textarea trumbowyg-ng ng-model="editorModel"></textarea>
```

See this at work here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FoCUDI?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I consider it to be a rather lacking directive, but it tends to be like that a lot with angular wrappers for jquery plugins.

The problem of course is that there is no way to access the trumbowyg element.
The easy way out is to give the element an id and just pick it up with angular.element.

```
<div trumbowyg-ng id="test" ...

$scope.trumbo = angular.element("#test");
$scope.trumbo.empty(); // (from the trumbowyg documentation)
```

It's not the *angular way(tm)* for sure. I suppose it would be prettier to make changes to the directive and make the trumbowyg-object available some other way. Sorry for being lazy.

Comment: Hummm.. I gave that a go but it's still not emptying out the editor. Any chance you can a provide an example within plunker? (just modify the one in the question)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I forgot to include `textarea`s in my Plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/Zbhr8oua5ssQLpAxH1Rw) which was giving me the trouble. Eventually I found that with `divs` and `$scope.trumbo['0'].textContent = '';` I got it to clear the editor :)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on ippi's answer I found `div`s instead of `textareas` and the following code solved my situation:

```
<div trumbowyg-ng id="trumbowyg" ...

$scope.trumbo = angular.element("#trumbowyg");
$scope.trumbo['0'].textContent = '';
```